# Facebook Graph API: shouldn't /userId/subscribers list subscribers for non-friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, subscription

From the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#subscribers

I was testing on Graph API Explorer and noticed that I can't get the public subscribers list from a non-friend person through that API connection even when I can see them via http://www.facebook.com/userId/subscribers page.

It retrieves only the `summary` info with `total_count`, nothing on `data`. Am I missing something or it's unsupported by design?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is by design, the API doesn't reflect the public interface, it's best not to think about it like this. Always see the permissions needed

> You can read the subscribers for a user for your app by issuing an HTTP GET request to /USER_ID/subscribers with the user access_token with the user_subscriptions or friends_subscriptions permission.

So as it says you can only read the authenticated user and the user's friends with the correct permissions.